# Delete Temporary session in PHP

Tags: php, session

How can I destroy a session in my database table. PHP coding will show at below :

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$session_id = session_id(); 
error_reporting(0);
include("db.php");
include("header.php"); 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $session_id=$session_id;
    $actual_price=$_POST['actual_price'];
    $gst=$_POST['gst'];
    $granttotal=$_POST['granttotal'];  
    $product_id=$_POST['product_id']; 
    $quantity=$_POST['quantity']; 
    /*$product_name=$_POST['product_name']; 
    $product_price=$_POST['product_price']; */

    foreach($product_id as $key => $pro){
    $qty = filter_var($quantity, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $pro = filter_var($pro, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    /*$proname = filter_var($product_name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $proprice = filter_var($product_price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);*/
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `checkout`(`session_id`,`actual_price`,`gst`,`granttotal`,`product_id`,`quantity`,`joinon`)VALUES ('$session_id','$actual_price','$gst','$granttotal','$pro','$qty','".date('Y-m-d')."')") or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_query("delete from cart where sessionid='$session_id'"); 
    echo ("<script>location.href='billing_info.php'</script>");

    }
}
```

Now for my purpose I deleted a session using delete query But session deleted but when again add a product it shows a same session. Then I realise we should destroy a session so please help me.

Comment: did you try with unset($variable) or session_destroy()

Comment: Yes, I did but thats not working

Comment: but where your variable is stored into session?

Comment: Please try with answer given below.. first store the variable into session, then you can destroy it using session_destroy or unset the variable

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it right then you want to destroy the current session so that you can reinitialize the cart according to the session id.

For destroying session in php you can use the below function after you perform the delete query successfully.

```
session_destroy();
```

For more info related to how to delete [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) , you may find here the official documentation of php related to it.

Using this function this will destroy all the session variables ie; it will unset all the session variables that is stored inside the $_SESSION global variable.

But if you want to delete only specific session variable then you can use the following code:

```
unset($_SESSOIN['variable_name'])
```

For more info related to how to [unset session variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Edit : If you want to regenerate the session id then use the [session_regenerate_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) function,

Comment: try another function then to regenerate session id - ie; [php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php] (session_regenerate_id())

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not working Session properly.

First store the variables in session such as :

```
$product_id=$_SESSION['product_id']; 
$quantity=$_SESSION['quantity'];
```

If you want to remove the session, use the destroy session function,

```
session_destroy();
```

and unset your variables from session like this:

```
unset($product_id);
unset($quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using php variables session_id() which changes its value on the clearing session from browser or you open the page in different session. if you are deleting it and inserting it again with closing the browser it won't change its value.

Instead you can use this session_regenerate_id() which regenerate its value when you create it again. Here is the Manual[enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

After successful delete operation do this below steps

1. // Unset all of the session variables.
   $_SESSION = array();
2. // Finally, destroy the session.
   session_destroy();

If it does not work then let me know your PHP version

Comment: my php version is PHP Version 5.6.31